# how do you generate a public key from a private key , from the command line, where keys were made with openssh

Tags: openssh

i'm having some difficulty  trying to generate  public key from private key , from the command line, where keys were made with openssh

(I know it's probably bad form to be root for this, but anyhow)

There are three private key files here.  hp_blah_id_rsa,  id_rsa, rodney

```
root@droplet-50-1:~/.ssh# ls -l
total 20
-rw------- 1 root root 1512 May 29 00:14 authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 root root 2602 May 28 23:15 hp_blah_id_rsa
-rw------- 1 root root 2602 May 28 23:28 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  222 May 28 21:47 known_hosts
-rw------- 1 root root 2602 May 28 21:17 rodney
```

as you see there's no .pub files there.

here the file command confirms they are private keys without me having to cat them!

```
root@droplet-50-1:~/.ssh# file hp_blah_id_rsa 
hp_blah_id_rsa: OpenSSH private key

root@droplet-50-1:~/.ssh# file rodney
rodney: OpenSSH private key

root@droplet-50-1:~/.ssh# file id_rsa
id_rsa: OpenSSH private key
```

I would like the public keys that can be derived from those private keys, in .pub files.

I saw this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244129/use-rsa-private-key-to-generate-public-key

and it mentions `openssl rsa -in mykey.pem -pubout > mykey.pub`

But that doesn't work for me e.g.

```
root@droplet-50-1:~/.ssh# openssl rsa -in id_rsa -pubout -out a.a
unable to load Private Key
140565827753280:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

Comment: OpenSSH keys and OpenSSL keys are not the same and are not cross-compatible.

Answer (score 2):

supposing the private key is `id_rsa`  then `ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa` will output the public key so you can do `ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa >id_rsa.pub`

Comment: from DT's comment on SO "This is not programming or development, but (1) the privatekey files created by OpenSSH 7.8 up (which is 7 years later than the very old Q .. linked{in the posted question}) cannot be read by OpenSSL and (2) when you can use OpenSSL the kind of publickey it creates is not the type created by OpenSSH and needed if you want to use it in OpenSSH. OTOH if you just kept reading, the Q ..linked{in the posted question} DOES give the correct way to create an OpenSSH publickey from an OpenSSH privatekey: ssh-keygen -y"

Comment: Maybe will be better to add your comment as part of the answer because the answer is more or less just one command w/o explaining the reason behind.

Comment: General FYI: `ssh-keygen -y -f <key>` will output a public key without a comment

Comment: @RomeoNinov the comment just gives some historical point about OpenSSL(which is not the command in my answer). .So, the comment doesn't explain whatever you think "the reasoning behind" the command  would be, whatever your phrase means anyhow.

Comment: @JW0914  You mention that the command will output without a comment. What "comment" would anybody expect ssh-keygen -y -f file,  to output?!?!